# Shell programming question moved to Super User

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

I recently answered a question about the availability of the `flock(1)` shell scripting utility on [OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X). This question has just been migrated to Super User and I'm not entirely sure why.

The question is [Mac OS X equivalent of Linux flock(1) command](https://superuser.com/questions/423865/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-linux-flock1-command)

The only use I can see for the `flock` command would be in a shell script. My answer stated that the `flock` command does not exist on OS X and that the alternative would be `shlock`, the `sh` in `shlock` stands for shell.

From the `shlock` man page:

> shlock -- create or verify a lock file for shell scripts

From the `flock` man page (on Linux):

> flock - Manage locks from shell scripts

Is shell scripting not considered *programming* on Stack Overflow? This migration doesn't seem correct to me!

Comment: While it might be possible to lock a file on the command line in an interactive shell I think it is much more likely the OP is trying to migrate a shell script from Linux to OS X.  The answer you point at also begs the question why this was moved to SuperUser and not Unix and Linux.  Either way this still feels like a bad migration to me.

Comment: I certainly grant you that this is one of those corner cases where a "perfect" spot for the question might have been any or all of the above under the right circumstances. I thought there was a better exemplar of a shell scripts question on Meta, but there are related ones http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/should-the-batch-file-programming-questions-be-moved-from-so-to-sf and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/where-questions-about-linux-shell-commands-go.  I'm not necessarily saying it was a correct migration, but just trying examine how it may have been interpreted.

Comment: You may have a point about U+L, their [faq](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) says: `The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not frontend application questions) [is on topic]`

Comment: @jonsca I'm not a mod on U&L, but I am a very active user there. mttrb: SU has a community migration path from SO, U&L doesn't. This question is on-topic on all of SO, SU, U&L and [apple.se]; it shouldn't have been migrated from where it was posted.

Comment: @Gilles I should have verified that before I wrote it.  You're a mod just about everywhere else, and that was an authoritative answer, so I just assumed, hehe.  My apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that shell programming, rather than interactive use, is **a topic properly handled by Stack Overflow, *not* by Superuser** I do not believe it should have been migrated.

However, I am increasingly in the minority in this. It’s almost as if the “real” programmers are taking a swipe at shell programming.

Since a good shell will allow you to construct on-the-fly *de facto* scripts by entering them in interactive mode, the distinction is blurry, leaving everything far too open to interpretation.

Comment: It sort of depends on why they ask the question. An answer on StackOverflow to a NT Batch or shell scripting question may be, "Shell scripting is a bad idea in this case; here's a 20 line Perl/C#/C program which does it better." On SuperUser, you're far less likely to get a response like that and far more likely to get the script you're looking for.

Comment: [unix.se] fields a lot of shell programming questions too. Shell scripting is on-topic both for programmer communities (because it's programming) and user and sysadmin communities (because it's automating a user/sysadmin task).

Comment: There has always been a problem with shell programming on SO because we have always had people coming and asking about shell primitives in ways that make it seem likely that they are just noodling at the command line. When I was more active on SO I used to jump on those with "Explain the programming context or risk migration" comments.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. It also looks like the migration was rejected at Super User (closed and deleted) shortly after you posted this.

I've reopened the [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526651/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-linux-flock1-command).

Comment: Out of curiosity's sake, why was it closed there?

Comment: Not sure. They probably just decided it shouldn't have been migrated either.

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, what’s a [Unicom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNICOM), anyway? :)

Comment: @tchrist it is unicorn. R N at the end, not M. (Ignore me if you were making a joke of which iI am blissfully unaware!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes, it was a joke.

Comment: @tchrist silly, silly me